# cakephp linking tables without using joins

Tags: cakephp

I just want to know how can I get the result of following query using cakephp's find (or similar) method.
select * from a, b where a.id = b.a_id

I know, same result can be achieved by using cakephp joins or query method.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work with the find method, your A and B model actually need to be associated. By the look of your query, you will need a `A hasMany B` relationship, but check [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) to verify what the correct association is for your situation.

You would do that by adding this to your `src/Model/Table/ATable.php` file:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->hasMany('B', [
        'foreignKey' => 'a_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ]);
}
```

After you have done that, you can use the contain method of the query finder to retrieve the data from the B model as well:

```
$query = $this->A->find('all')->contain(['B']);
```

Or if you are still using CakePHP 2.x (your question doesn't really cover that), it would be your `app/Model/A.php` file and the association code looks a bit different:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'B' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'a_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

And then to find the data from both tables:

```
// Make sure this is included in your (App)Model:
public $actsAs = array('Containable');

// Then find the data
$this->A->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array('B')
));
```